# loading corrupt swf file didn't show any error

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash

In my app, I need to load some external swf files. I used following code:

```
var file:File;
file = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("myfolder/myfile.swf");
if(file.exists)
{
    var inFileStream:FileStream = new FileStream(); 
    inFileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ); 
    var swfBytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    inFileStream.readBytes(swfBytes);
    inFileStream.close();

    var loaderContext:LoaderContext = new LoaderContext(false, new ApplicationDomain(null));
    loaderContext.allowLoadBytesCodeExecution = true;
    loaderContext.allowCodeImport = true;
    myLoader = new Loader();
    try
    {
        myLoader.loadBytes(swfBytes, loaderContext);
    }
    catch(e:Error)
    {
        trace("Can't read file.");
    }
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LoadComplete_swf);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop, false, 0, true);
    myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,loadingError);
}
else
{
     trace("File doesn't exists.");
}
```

Everything works fine. But I recently found out some of my swf files are corrupted. When loading those files, it doesn't dispatch complete event and it also doesn't throw any error. So, my question is, is there any way to find if swf file is corrupted or not? Yes I can replace those corrupt swf files. This is just a precaution if this kind of problem occurs again. At the moment, all I can think of is to create a timer and check if complete event is dispatch or not. If not then show can't read file message. Is there any better way of dealing with this?

Comment: To test the integrity of the file hash it and compare the result to your expected value. bloody crypto library is recommended.

Comment: Documentation states it's IO_ERROR event for such a case.

Comment: @Organis, IO_ERROR didn't fire. It only fires when the file of the size was zero.

Comment: @TheGunners I just made a check and confirmed it. If the source bytes do not represent a valid SWF, or JPG, or PNG, or any other format, suitable for **Loader**, it indeed fires IO_ERROR. That means your file is not corrupted in terms of format.

Answer (score 1):

When a file is corrupt all sort of unexpected things might happen. Setting a timeout is a good way to handle no events loading issues. As suggested by @seventeen you can use the crypto library to verify file hash, but this requires that you already have a hash to compare to, and that the load complete event is fired.

Comment: I don't have hash to compare. The total number of files are unknown to me so saving hash also be a problem.

Comment: Then setting a reasonable timeout makes sense. Since you do not know the size of files, timeout should be reset not just by load complete but also by load progress.